# Force webpage to use a specific font

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have created a question mark button using the Arial font.

The CSS looks like this:

```
.question {
    font: bold 24px Arial;
}
```

It appears correctly on almost all browsers, as this screenshot shows.

[image: 1]

However, newer versions of Android use the Roboto font face instead of Arial. The question mark is now off-center and the wrong width.

[image]

My question: is it possible to force the browser to use Arial?

Comment: `font-family: bold 24px Arial;` is not valid css. `font-family` must be a list of fonts, so `bold 24px` must not be there. This property rule should not be applied by any browser. `font: bold 24px Arial;` on the other hand would be valid. Are you sure it is `font-family`?

Comment: You cannot force a device/computer which doesn't have Arial installed to use it. You would have to rely on webfonts to use Arial everywhere. Also, your syntax is wrong, you should be using the shorthand property `font`, and not `font-family` (which is only used to specify the font face and potential fallbacks), like so: `font: bold 24px Arial, sans-serif;`

Comment: @t.niese yes that was a typo, thanks.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen feel free to add that as an actual answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot force a device/computer which doesn't have Arial installed to use it. You would have to rely on webfonts to use Arial everywhere.

Also, your syntax is wrong, you should be using the shorthand property `font`, and not `font-family` (which is only used to specify the font face and potential fallbacks), like so:

```
.question {
    font: bold 24px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```